# Intercooler.js - ic-target reloads intercooler-code and then is not working anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I am using intercooler.js in a django project.

http://intercoolerjs.org

```
<div id=right_side>

<form ic-post-to="{% url 'update-task-ajax' %}" ic-target="#right_side">
[...]
</form>

</div>
```

The form itself gets reloaded in the div #right-side after the first (working) use and after that intercooler is not working anymore. How to fix this?

**Update:**

Looks like i have to use

```
Intercooler.ready(func(elt))
```

http://intercoolerjs.org/reference.html

But i'm stuck how to use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong about this, the form should keep submitting and targeting #right_side each time, unless you are replacing it somehow.  I don't see why `Intercooler.ready()` is necessary, given the code.  Can you clarify what are trying to accomplish?

I'm availabe on the gitter chat for intercooler to help:

https://gitter.im/intercooler-js/Lobby